# Always display the end of the document TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

hello  code is this:

```
    <script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector:'textarea',
        plugins: "noneditable",
        noneditable_leave_contenteditable: true,
        menubar: false,
        toolbar: false,
        mode : "textareas",
        body_class: "",
        readonly : true
    });

<textarea id="ciao" disabled="true">
    <strong>tizio:</strong> Caricato una foto.<br>
    <strong>tizio:</strong> Caricato una foto.<br>
    <strong>tizio:</strong> Caricato una foto.<br>
    <strong>tizio:</strong> Caricato una foto.<br>
    <strong>tizio:</strong> Caricato una foto.<br>
    <strong>tizio:</strong> Caricato una foto.<br>
    <strong>tizio:</strong> Caricato una foto.<br>
    <strong>tizio:</strong> Caricato una foto.<br>
    <strong>tizio:</strong> Caricato una foto.<br>
    <strong>tizio:</strong> Caricato una foto.<br>
    <strong>tizio:</strong> Caricato una foto.<br>
    <strong>tizio:</strong> Caricato una foto.<br>
    <strong>tizio:</strong> Caricato una foto.<br>
    <strong>tizio:</strong> Caricato una foto.<br>

</textarea>
```

I want to implement a chat, but I can not ever render the end of the document! Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You haven't `</script>`...

Comment: Sorry, i have yet add </script>! but my problem is not resolved :( ! cAN YOU HELP ME ??